# Help with gmail?

Tags: samsung, gmail

I know I'm going to sound very silly because I'm not very good at all this. I only became a teenager last week... Anyway, a couple of weeks ago, my mom got a new phone. She said I could have her old phone because I wanted to get a game that wasn't available to download on my iPad. But today, I wanted to change the gmail on the phone and change it to mine, so I set a new one up like 30 minutes ago. I went into settings and I signed out her Gmail from the old phone ( her gmail wasn't synced and I don't know what that means haha because I'm a silly person ) I went into Gmail app and I noticed that ALL OF HER EMAILS WERE ON MY NEW EMAIL :( Did I delete her account and change it to mine? I don't know what to do. I don't understand. This is probably stupid to you guys but I'm afraid I did something bad. Please help me. I'm actually scared I did something wrong to it. Please reply in a easy way how to fix it because I'm not good at all this stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: Just clear the data and cache for the gmail app at Settings > Apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not stupid at all, the fact that you don't understand something is not a reason for stupidity, is just you don't have knowledge about it.

And there is no problem with the Gmail account, the mails you are seeing are stored in your phone, accounts are never lost since they are in Google server.

Comment: For single quote marks, use ', not `.

Comment: The best bet here would be to delete the Google account from the phone, and perform a factory reset... otherwise there will always be "remnants" of your mothers data on the device. Then set it up as a new device. This would be the cleanest method.

Comment: Oh thank you :) So all of my moms emails were just stored on my phone and she still has them on her new one and on the laptop?

Comment: Yes, all mail is in the google account, just sign in.